# Hover function trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I made this [website](http://www.shamuzzi.com) and when you hover over the COLLECTION tab on the top navbar or over the sidebar the bottom content slides down which is exactly I want. But my problem is that when I hover out it pop backs up which is not what I want. Although its not a toggle function I set but it seems to be working like it. Can somebody help me?

```
$('.down').hover(function() {
    $('.b2-a .has_scroll').stop().animate({
        height: "22px"
    }, 500);
    $('.b2-b .slide-div').stop().animate({
        height: "19px"
    }, 500);
    $("#slide-title h4").show();
    $(".slide-div").animate({
        marginTop: "-12px"
    });
    $('.b2 .tancar').animate({
        backgroundPosition: '28px 4px'
    })
}, function() {
    $('.b2-a .has_scroll').stop().animate({
        height: "120px"
    }, 500);
    $('.b2-b .slide-div').stop().animate({
        height: "438px"
    }, 500);
    $("#slide-title h4").hide();
    $(".slide-div").animate({
        marginTop: "-12px"
    });
    $('.b2 .tancar').animate({
        backgroundPosition: '28px -19px'
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to rethink your code.  It looks like you've got it sliding up on many different events.  Do you want it to slide up on click of the button and on hover?  If so, do something like this:

```
$('.b2').hover(function() {
  // do animation to show
));
$('#clic').click(function() {
  // do animation to show
));
$('.b2').mouseout(function() {
  // do animation to hide
));
```

Comment: Thanks user1477388, I know its very buggy and I need to learn more and be more logically. Much appreciated!